# T-SQL How to grant role to user

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

After creating roles and granting privileges to them, I want to grant the privileges of a specified role to a user, how to do with it? I tried grant  to , but failed.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

```
EXEC sp_addrolemember 'db_owner', 'JohnJacobs'
```

---

Just to let people in the future know, MS official [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187750.aspx) now specifies that this approach is being deprecated. ALTER ROLE is recommended intead.

Comment: Just to let people in the future know, MS official [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187750.aspx) now specifies that this approach is being deprecated and `sp_addrolemember` will dissapear from future releases. ALTER ROLE is the recommended way now, so follow @samp answer instead.

Answer (score 110):

Because BOL shows sp_addrolemember has been deprecated, if you are using SQL Server 2012 you may want to use:

```
ALTER ROLE <role_name> ADD MEMBER <user_name>
```

Comment: Interesting, as if this is the case then you would expect SSMS to support generation of such scripts. Which it does not.

Comment: It is also worth to note that you might need to execute `CREATE USER [user_name] FOR LOGIN [user_name] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]` before that. In my case I had to do that before it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I needed to add the user to the public role for a specific database.  This is done as so:

```
USE [<DB Name>]
GO
CREATE USER [<User Name>] FOR LOGIN [<User Name>]
GO
```