# Windows Impersonation and SQL rights

Tags: c#, sql-server, impersonation

I've used the technique in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003417/how-do-i-use-impersonation-on-a-c-sharp-winforms-application-to-run-with-admin-p) to impersonate the Windows User who has admin rights over a database. I thought that this would allow the process to alter tables etc (which if I'm logged on as that person I'm able to). My connection string uses `IntegratedSecurity` and after I prompt the user for db admin username & password I impersonate that user and then reconnect to the database. I thought this would allow me to create tables etc, but no ...

**Is there something else I need to do to give my program (temporary) admin rights to my database?**

I've tried following the impersonation with `EXECUTE AS LOGIN = @user`, but it wasn't happy - do I need to supply a password to SQL as well to make that work, perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either [add a role](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3998634/964043) to the logins you want to use, or [grant specific permissions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11008399/964043). The second is typically the preferred method, as you can be much more granular in the amount of access provided to the account.

Comment: I don't want to give the user any permissions - they have a restricted role for a reason! I want the administrator to be able to sit at the machine and type in his/her credentials that will be used temporarily to update the database.

Comment: Then you would have to run the APPLICATION in a different user context.

Comment: So impersonation isn't enough, then?

Comment: Correct, as the SQL Server only can see the login context for the logged in account.

Answer (score 0):

You may well be having a problem with the Connection Pool. When a process closes a connection, the connection is not in fact closed, but goes to the processes Connection Pool. The next time that process tries to open a connection it will get one from the pool if that connection in the pool has the same connection string as the requested new connection.
Thus you likely aren't getting a new connection at all, but an already opened one with the auths of the original opener.

The only way around this I can see is to use a different connection string for the admin user: add or remove a clause that makes no difference (e.g. 'MARS Connection=true' or something). That should work.

Cheers -

Comment: Tried that but it now says the server is not accessible!! - seems to hate the new user ... "SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified"

Comment: What does the changes connection string look like?

Comment: I changed the connection timeout to 17

Comment: `"Data Source=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=autumn;Integrated Security=True;Connection Timeout=15"`
to  
`"Data Source=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=autumn;Integrated Security=True;Connection Timeout=17"`

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that the new user doesn't have access to the folder where the mdb is stored. If that's all you've changed then I can;t think of anything else (I don't use SQLExpress much I'm afraid).