# SQL Syntax Error Creating Roles

Tags: sql, sql-server

Keep getting an error when trying to grant a specific role to user:

```
Grant role role_1 to maintenance;
```

Error:

> Incorrect syntax near 'role_1'

Want to edit it so the Grant role to user works

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11008399/t-sql-how-to-grant-role-to-user) is your answer for SQL Server

Comment: I can't see what the Grant Role role_1 fix was on SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

```
GRANT {role_name} TO {user_name};
```

for T-SQL, Here's the simplified syntax for [GRANT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187965.aspx)

```
GRANT { ALL [ PRIVILEGES ] }
      | permission [ ( column [ ,...n ] ) ] [ ,...n ]
      [ ON [ class :: ] securable ] TO principal [ ,...n ] 
      [ WITH GRANT OPTION ] [ AS principal ]
```

in your case, simply

```
GRANT role_1 TO maintenance;
```

Comment: Thanks but still getting Syntax Error for some reason